# Excel macro loop code for more than one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for delimited columns for one sheet. How do I make this code for more than sheets with looping?

```
Sub Macro1()

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy;@"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub t()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        'do what you want, for example, 
        Range("A1:B10").TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
            :="_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy;@"
    Next
End Sub
```

However, you should not use `Selection`. You should use a `range` instead, for e.g. `Range("A1:B10")`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim x As Long
Dim ws As Sheets

For x = 1 To 12'<--to as how many is required
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Activate
    Call Macro1  '<---the name of your macro
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```